# Visual Code intellisense transform clg to ChannelMergerNode

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, console.log

In Visual Studio Code, I'd like to keep the shortcut `clg` to be transformed to `console.log`, but sometimes it's transformed `ChannelMergerNode`. Is there any way to fix it?
Thank you in advance.